# How to implement a Priority Queue in numba where one element of the item is a list of tuples?

Tags: python, types, priority-queue, numba

I am trying to create the PriorityQueue in numba for a very specific task. To achieve that, I need the nodes to have an element which is list of tuples. However, when I try to do that, it raises an error that I don't understand.

(Most of the implementation of PriorityQueue taken from [How can I implement a numba jitted priority queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585821/how-can-i-implement-a-numba-jitted-priority-queue))

```py
import typing
from heapq import heappush, heappop
import numba as nb
from numba.experimental import jitclass


itemType = nb.typed.List.empty_list(nb.types.Tuple((nb.types.int64, nb.types.int64)))
entry_def = (0.0, 0, nb.typed.List([(0,0)]))
entry_type = nb.typeof(entry_def)

@jitclass
class PriorityQueue:
    pq: typing.List[entry_type]
    id: int
    entry: entry_type

    def __init__(self):
        self.pq = nb.typed.List.empty_list((0.0, 0, nb.typed.List([(0,0)])))

    def put(self, priority: float, id: int, item: itemType):
        entry = (priority, id, item)
        heappush(self.pq, entry)

    def pop(self):
        if self.pq:
            priority, id, item = heappop(self.pq)
            return priority, id, item
        raise KeyError("pop from an empty priority queue")
```

The functionality that I need to achieve:

```py
>>> q = PriorityQueue() 
>>> q.put(5.0, 1, [(0,1)])
>>> q.put(2.0, 2, [(0,1), (1,2)])
>>> q.put(3.0, 3, [(0,1), (0,1), (1,1)])
>>> node = q.pop()
>>> node
(2.0, 2, [(0, 1), (1, 2)])
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\VS Code\myproject.py", line 34, in <module>
    q.put(5.0, 1, [(0,1)])
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\experimental\jitclass\boxing.py", line 61, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function heappush>) found for signature:

 >>> heappush(ListType[Tuple(float64, int64, ListType[UniTuple(int64 x 2)])], Tuple(float64, int64, reflected list(UniTuple(int64 x 2))<iv=None>))

There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload in function 'heappush': File: numba\cpython\heapq.py: Line 150.
    With argument(s): '(ListType[Tuple(float64, int64, ListType[UniTuple(int64 x 2)])], Tuple(float64, int64, reflected list(UniTuple(int64 x 2))<iv=None>))':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     TypingError: heap type must be the same as item type
  raised from C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\cpython\heapq.py:119

During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in function heappush>)
During: typing of call at C:\VS Code\myproject.py (24)


File "myproject.py", line 24:
    def put(self, priority: float, id: int, item: itemType):
        <source elided>
        entry = (priority, id, item)
        heappush(self.pq, entry)
        ^

- Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
None

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.core.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'put') for instance.jitclass.PriorityQueue#228d8eebd30<pq:ListType[Tuple(float64, int64, ListType[UniTuple(int64 x 2)])],id:int64,entry:Tuple(float64, int64, ListType[UniTuple(int64 x 2)])>)
During: typing of call at <string> (3)


File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the inferred type for a Python list is a reflected list, but your lists are Numba typed lists. If you do:

```py
q.put(5.0, 1, nb.typed.List([(0, 1)]))
q.put(2.0, 2, nb.typed.List([(0, 1), (1, 2)]))
q.put(3.0, 3, nb.typed.List([(0, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1)]))
```

then your code runs to completion and produces:

```
(2.0, 2, ListType[UniTuple(int64 x 2)]([(0, 1), (1, 2)]))
```